# error on accessing a property of a control in a wpf user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

i have created a wpf user control with a text box and a combo box.
for accessing the text property of the text box i have used the below code

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextP = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxUnitConvertor));

public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return txtValue.Text; }
    set { txtValue.Text = value; }
}
```

in another project i have used the control and bind the text as below:

```
<textboxunitconvertor:TextBoxUnitConvertor Name="wDValueControl" TextBoxText="{Binding _FlClass.SWa_SC.Value , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="161" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

i am certain that the class that is used for binding is properly working because when i used it to bing with a text box directly in my project it works properly but when i bind it to the text property of textbox in usercontrol it brings null and the binding does not work.
can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependency property declaration is wrong. It has to look like shown below, where the getter and setter of the CLR property wrapper call the GetValue and SetValue methods:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxUnitConvertor));

public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
}
```

In the XAML of your UserControl, you would bind to the property like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxText,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

---

If you need to get notified whenever the `TextBoxText` property changes, you could register a PropertyChangedCallback with PropertyMetadata passed to the Register method:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxUnitConvertor),
        new PropertyMetadata(TextBoxTextPropertyChanged));

private static void TextBoxTextPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxUnitConvertor t = (TextBoxUnitConvertor)o;
    t.CurrentValue = ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. another question. if i need to bind the created property "TextBoxText" to another property like below, how can i do that.        private double _CurrentValue;
        [Browsable(false)]
        public double CurrentValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _CurrentValue;
            }
            set { _CurrentValue = value; }
        }

Comment: Register a PropertyChangedCallback as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: very good. but if ineed two way binding, how it can be? it means that if the user changed the text of the textbox iin the user control, the binded class in the main project change accordintg to it?

Comment: That should already work, because the "internal" TextBox binding is two-way by default.

Comment: it's true. but for example i have some property in the control that does not have XAML representative. i need to bind them in two way mode to a dependancy object that is registered as you said. How can I do that?

Comment: please see these question which i created:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693358/set-a-property-of-user-control-as-a-dependancy-object-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the dependency property right. Use this code:

```
public string TextBoxText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
        }

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxUnitConvertor), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

Then in your custom control **Bind** the `TextBoxText` to the value of `txtValue.Text`