# wpf Rectangle acts weird when changing properties

Tags: c#, wpf

**Situation**:

i have a custom WPF UserControl which should be like the toggle Buttons from most mobile OS.
[image: my UserControl]

It should change from one state to another when clicking on it once.

**My Problem**
Sometimes the just don't work the way I want. Either the rectangles disappear or the red/gray background rectangles won't be colored. 
[image: Problem image 1]

or they will be drawn twice or so.

**My Code**
I have a Grid:
In there is one Grid for the Background rectangels
and the 3 "SelectRectangles" are in there in different columns.

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.StatusControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="80">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!-- my dummy values -->

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="DarkGray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TSBackgroundBrush" Color="Gray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TSBarBrush" Color="LightGreen" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush1" Color="Khaki" />


        <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="SliderRectangleStyle">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource TSBarBrush}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="2" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="4" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="LeftFillRectangleStyle">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush1}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,0,2" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="4" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="TextLabelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Aus" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Client" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Finance Dept." />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle 
        Margin="5,2,5,2" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
        Fill="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" 
        Stroke="{DynamicResource TSBackgroundBrush}"
        />

        <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="5" 
        Style="{StaticResource TextLabelStyle}"
        Margin="4,0,4,0" 
        />

        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LeftFillRectangleStyle}" />
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource SliderRectangleStyle}" />

        <!-- Overlay the slider area with three equal click areas -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <!-- 
            Because this style has no x:Key, it will apply to all Rectangles in this Grid 
            -->
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle" >
                    <!-- 
                Uncomment these setters to make sure the clickable areas are where 
                they should be.
                -->
                    <!--
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
               -->
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="StatusSelect_PreviewMouseDown" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am setting the visibility to hidden/visible accordingly, since moving one Rectangle, happened to come up with the same problem.

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für StatusControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StatusControl : UserControl
    {
        public StatusControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Status Property
        public int Status {
            get { return (int)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Status), typeof(int), typeof(StatusControl),new PropertyMetadata(0));
        #endregion Status Property

        private void StatusSelect_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Status = Grid.GetColumn(sender as UIElement);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:StatusControl Status="1"/>
        <local:StatusControl Status="2"/>
        <local:StatusControl Status="3"/>
        <Slider x:Name="TestSlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="2" Width="200"/>
        <local:StatusControl Status="{Binding Value, ElementName=TestSlider}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**My tried solutions**
It seems that they just don't update. I tried calling this.UpdateLayout() but it did not help. Sometimes the also redraw themselves after a few seconds an then its okey. Sometimes not...

Thank you for reading/helping!

Comment: Instead of making 3 rect, I would use 1 rect and animate the Top/Left properties to make it slide smoothly from one position to the next.

Comment: Your problem is the C# code. Everything you're doing can and should be done in XAML.

Comment: Yup I had one rectangle first only. But it had the same problems or was even worse.

Comment: Mhh okey I'll look into that. Thank you for the hint

Comment: Do you happen to know any sources for me to read through?

Comment: @Eric.Volli I'm writing a quick example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's give your status control a `Status` dependency property. I don't know what your control is called or what the `status` variable you have is all about, so I'll just call my control `StatusControl`. I think you might be better off with an enum for `Status` instead of an int (`Good`, `Indifferent`, `Bad`, or `Error`, `Warning`, `Success` or something like that). But I'll stick with your `int` for now.

```
public partial class StatusControl : UserControl
{
    public StatusControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Status Property
    public int Status
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Status), typeof(int), typeof(StatusControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(0));
    #endregion Status Property

    private void StatusSelect_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Status = Grid.GetColumn(sender as UIElement);
    }
}
```

And that `Status` property drives the changes in the user control via the `Triggers` in the two rectangle styles.

- `SliderRectangleStyle` dynamically repositions a single rectangle representing the slider.
- `LeftFillRectangleStyle` dynamically shows/hides and resizes a rectangle that fills in the accent-color area of the slider.

You may have to fine-tune the margins a bit to get the exact proportions you had originally; I was pretty casual when I ripped apart your original XAML.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- my dummy values -->
    <!-- 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="DarkGray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TSBackgroundBrush" Color="Gray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TSBarBrush" Color="LightGreen" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush1" Color="Khaki" />
    -->

    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="SliderRectangleStyle">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource TSBarBrush}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="2" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="4" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="LeftFillRectangleStyle">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush1}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,0,2" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="4" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TextLabelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Aus" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Client" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Finance Dept." />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle 
        Margin="5,2,5,2" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
        Fill="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" 
        Stroke="{DynamicResource TSBackgroundBrush}"
        />

    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="5" 
        Style="{StaticResource TextLabelStyle}"
        Margin="4,0,4,0" 
        />

    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LeftFillRectangleStyle}" />
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource SliderRectangleStyle}" />

    <!-- Overlay the slider area with three equal click areas -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <!-- 
            Because this style has no x:Key, it will apply to all Rectangles in this Grid 
            -->
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle" >
                <!-- 
                Uncomment these setters to make sure the clickable areas are where 
                they should be.
                -->
                <!--
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
                -->
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="StatusSelect_PreviewMouseDown" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you alot for the answer! I'll test it out and then come back to mark your post as an answer (if it works - what I strongly believe)

Comment: @Eric.Volli Cool. Do you need to make text a property as well, like `Status`, or should it always be `"Aus"`? That's easy to set up.

Comment: Might be a very stupid question (I am quite new to xaml)
I get the error that the element Status could not be accessed... Am I missing a reference?

Comment: My use case is the following: I need to export bills. In that export-Window I have lots of toggle Buttons. But to export bills I wanted to have a control that was able to have three states: 1.) Off (Aus is off in german) 2.) client and 3.) finance department. I wanted to set the Text property accordingly and simply switch - case the status int...

Comment: @Eric.Volli 1. I'd have to see your version of the code to understand the problem with `Status`. 2. I'll do an update for the text thing. You could figure out that part for yourself from what I did with the rectangles, though.

Comment: @Eric.Volli See update. I'm really enjoying this. I'd like to figure out what you're seeing with that error about `Status`, though. The code just as I have it is working fine here.

Comment: 1.) I copied your code into a test project. The error message is: "member is not recognized or is not accessible" i googled it and there the problem was that taht guy did not use a DependencyProperty. I couldn't find an answer...

Comment: Once again Thank you! for helping me so much!

Comment: @Eric.Volli I need to see your version of my code. Clearly, there's something in the test project you created that's not the same as mine.

Comment: `    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:StatusControl Status="1"/>
            <local:StatusControl Status="2"/>
            <local:StatusControl Status="3"/>
            <Slider x:Name="TestSlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="2" Width="200"/>
            <local:StatusControl Status="{Binding Value, ElementName=TestSlider}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid> 
` 

just copied it... (Can't get the code-format working right now... I'm feeling a little bit stupid...)

Comment: You are doing something different. I don't know what. I can't tell you what without seeing what you did. This is the simplest possible case of a dependency property. I've done this a thousand times. There are no subtleties here.

Comment: You need the ending backtick, but you should be putting sizable blocks of code in your question anyway, not in comments where it can't be read.

Comment: You just showed me the test code. That's nothing. That just creates an instance of a user control that you must define. I gave you all the code for that usercontrol. Did you create a usercontrol called StatusControl, paste my UserControl XAML into the XAML file, and use my C# code in the .xaml.cs file?

Comment: Ah I see what you did with the rectangles! Just as a side-note: The original thaught was to cycle through the states and not acutally be able to set them by clicking into different areas...

Comment: @Eric.Volli Right, I thought that was likely the case, since you had only one clickable area. But then I got to thinking how I'd do it if it were me.

Comment: @Eric.Volli OK, so show me the XAML in MainWindow.xaml. The whole thing, in your question.

Comment: Is a control called StatusControl defined in the namespace `test`, and does it have a DependencyProperty called `Status`?

Comment: both yes... Intellignese proposes "Status" so its kind of there.

Comment: @Eric.Volli Is this just the designer acting up? Does it run with a clean build?

Comment: The userControl Designer works fine. The MainWondow one not. And it is not building...

Comment: @Eric.Volli Let's see StatusControl.xaml.cs, again the whole file.

Comment: May I see StatusControl.xaml.cs please, the C# codebehind file?

Comment: btw: I really like your solution with the three different clickable areas! Very smart!

Comment: I don't know what could have caused the error you're seeing. I'm at a loss. Sorry.

Comment: But you can certainly recreate a new, identical dependency property in your own user control, and use my XAML.

Comment: mhh... No problem you tried alot...
The guy within this question has the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692232/error-on-accessing-a-property-of-a-control-in-a-wpf-user-control?rq=1

Comment: I looked at the accepted answer but it seems that your provided code implements that perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the same problem, it's just the same symptom. I create dependency properties with a snippet so it gets the name of the static property right automatically. One thing you might try is commenting the XAML where the control is used in MainWindow, building, then restoring MainWindow after it's built. The designer has trouble with properties that haven't been part of a build yet, so perhaps the designer is preventing the initial build that the designer needs before it can work.

Comment: Ho that did the trick!
Okey so know i feel double stupid...

Thank you for helping! I saw the working code the first time now so now I can mark your answer as the accepted one!

Comment: How stupid do you think I feel?! I've had that problem a dozen times and went totally blank when you had it too.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to write stuff like "thank you" into comments but: Thank you! Must have taken you quite some time...

Comment: @Eric.Volli WPF goes pretty quick once you get used to it. Glad to help.